# FPS Camera using JOGL and gluLookAt

Tags: opengl, camera, jogl

In display i have:

```
Camera c = new Camera(canvas);
glu.gluLookAt(c.eyeX, c.eyeY, c.eyeZ, c.point_X, c.point_Y, c.point_Z, 0, 1, 0);
```

those variables are from an object from my Camera class which has:

```
float eyeX = 5.0f, eyeY = 5.0f, eyeZ = 5.0f;
float camYaw = 0.0f;       //camera rotation in X axis
float camPitch = 0.0f;     //camera rotation in Y axis
float point_X = 10.0f;
float point_Y = 5.0f;
float point_Z = 5.0f;
```

i calculate the delta on the mouse movement and camYaw goes from 0 to 360 degrees
and camPitch from -90 to 90 degrees (or 0 - 2PI and -+PI/2)

this works fine but when i put the calculated point_X, point_Y, point_Z to the gluLookAt() it moves the cam in a strange way (seems it rotates the camera to an invisible sphere depending on the given radius in the equasions)

```
public void updateCamera() {
float radius = 5.0f;

point_X = (float) (radius * Math.cos(camYaw) * Math.sin(camPitch));
point_Z = (float) (radius * Math.sin(camPitch) * Math.sin(camYaw));
point_Y = (float) (radius * Math.cos(camPitch));

}
```

Im trying to convert polar to cartesian coordinates.

The larger the radius the better it "works".

Changing from degrees to radians still doesnt work.

Comment: `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()`, etc. uses radians are you sure that you don't use degrees?

Comment: tried both radians and degrees, no result